# Can't see new questions on SO (tagged questions)

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface

- Please can you to check whats heppened with engine on SO, because I can see question more than one hour old

[image]

- [can't see my test question (testing) too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477360/how-to-see-html-contents-in-jtextarea)
- PC restarted, user log off/log on
- on Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1, on Win8

Comment: Verified, same problem here.  I can see new questions as they come in, but if I refresh the page, they are lost...

Comment: PC restarted? Seriously? You're a die hard SO fan..

Comment: @Mr. Alien hehehe I'm Win workstations/server, Solaris OS admin, then always ... :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interesting. We flipped our primary/secondary redis servers (so the slave is the master and the master is the slave) at about that time; I guess part of the system didn't spot the change and got a bit grumpy. I took a hammer to them - they seem happier now.

Comment: now is everything (looks like as) o.k., status was changed from funny k.o., valid for me from all StackOverflow sites where I member of (registred:-)

Comment: *"I took a hammer to them..."* The [old ways](http://www.earthtothemoon.com/apollo_12.html) are frequently the best. :-)

Comment: ah, I posted a question about it, then deleted it and cursed my network guys for the behviour, I guess now I owe them an apology