# Newest questions appear with delay

Tags: bug, status-norepro, newest-questions

After being stale for ~18 minutes I've started to see new questions but as "asked 18 mins ago" (and more), so with a huge time delay. This is on main page Questions -> newest. I do find this quite annoying...

I know, similar things happen now and then

[Can't see new questions on SO (tagged questions)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179662/cant-see-new-questions-on-so-tagged-questions)

["Newest" questions sometimes appears to be stale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147517/newest-questions-sometimes-appears-to-be-stale)

[Newest questions not updating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179667/newest-questions-not-updating)

[New questions page - caches for too long?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147488/new-questions-page-caches-for-too-long)

and issue dates back several years it seems.

But going through a few of these queries I found, some are simply marked as duplicate and some have answers/comments along the lines of "we'll look at it". However, since the issue is old and even if someone has fixed it previously, this is not a duplicate since it is not supposed to happen any more. All in all, closing question as duplicate to a question with no real answer is not a very good practice.

What I'm trying to find out is some conclusion on this. Either "this is really hard to fix and we won't do it" or "we are still looking at it, and going to fix it and write it here when done".